# Node NPM - install versus install -g

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am a node newbie and am somewhat confused with the whole "install" thing.

What is the difference between `install`, and `install -g`?

Can something installed with `install -g` be accessed anywhere, or does this make it available to the Node server but not your application? Is there any reason to use one, and not the other?

Cheers

Comment: Isn't it detailed here? https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the node.js blog:

- If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of your project.
- If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

So for example, lets say you wanted to install the Grunt CLI. Odds are you'll use Grunt in multiple projects, so you'll want to install that *globally* using `-g`.

Now lets say you're working on a project and your project is going to require a module such as Express. You would `cd` to your projects root directory and install the module **without** `-g`.

[Here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) is a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`install` means the module will be created in your *local* `node_modules` folder which is highly recommended for anything your application relies on (for versioning, amongst other reasons).

`install -g` means install the module **globally** on your machine. This is *generally* only recommended to use with modules that perform some task unrelated to the execution of your application.

Simple examples of this are [Yeoman generators](http://yeoman.io/), the [Express generator](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable), [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), etc.

There is an official blog post about it [here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is `npm install mod` will install it in your local directory. Let's say you are working in 'projectA' directory. So

```
> npm install mod
```

will install "mod" in

```
> projectA/node_modules/mod/
```

so any `.js` file inside projectA can use this module by just saying `require('mod')`

whereas 'npm install mod -g` will install it globally in the user's node module directory. It will be somewhere in

```
> /usr/bin/npm/node_modules/modA
```

you can use this module anywhere in any of your project, in addition to that if there is any terminal command is there in 'modA'. It will be accessible from you terminal directory.

```
> modA --version
> version 1.1
```